# Why Brownian motion is a stationary process

Tags: brownian-motion, stationary-processes

I found out that I simply can't rigorously prove that Wiener process is a stationary process, i.e. its finite-dimensional distributions don't change under shift in time. Let $W_t$ be a Wiener process:

1. $W_0=0$ a.s.
2. for $0\le t_0\le \ldots \le t_n$ random variables $W_{t_n}-W_{t_{n-1}}, \ldots, W_{t_2}-W_{t_{1}}, W_{t_1}-W_{t_{0}}$ are independent,
3. $W_{t}-W_{s}\sim N(0, t-s)$.

Then why $W_t$ is a stationary process, i.e. for any measurable set $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\mathbb{P}((W_{t_1},\ldots, W_{t_n})\in A)=\mathbb{P}((W_{t_1+h},\ldots, W_{t_n+h})\in A)?
$$

For instance, if I take $n=1$, then of course $\mathbb{P}(W_{t}\in A)\neq \mathbb{P}(W_{t+h}\in A)$ because $W_{t}$ and $W_{t+h}$ dont have same distribution.

Sorry for probably simple question, but I seemed to get stuck.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/964735/532409 (Brownian motion has stationary increments)

Answer (score 13):

Brownian motion *isn't* a stationary process in this sense.

What is true is that it has stationary *increments*: that for any $s,t$ and any $h$, $W_t - W_s$ has the same distribution as $W_{t+h}-W_{s+h}$.  This is essentially what is expressed by your property 3.  This is usually what people mean when they speak of Brownian motion being "stationary".

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer!

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3315356/73467) explains why Brownian motion can't be stationary.